# Post request rendering an object

Tags: javascript, express

I am working on a web application where many people are supposed to connect and one is going to act as an admin. The users can only proceed to the next stage if the admin has allowed the access.

At the moment, I am wondering how should I realize the access control.

In the first version, I was doing an ajax get request when a user clicks the next button, and then if a specific word is present, I proceed. The admin was supposed to modify the page manually. Now I would like to automate it and make it more user-friendly (as the admin does not go to the code manually modifying).

My idea is, there is going to be radio boxes which by clicking, the admin can allow or disallow access.  However, to achieve this, my idea was to make an ajax post request to the server when admin selects one and then modifying some keyword in a hidden page. Is this approach feasible or am I completely wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Does the users login first to proceed e.g how they access the system ? A user whom access you wanted to restrict must have something unique associated to it. And you can have his/her data updated upon access update through radio buttons. Any particular user connects to the system only his/her access rights are checked into the system

Comment: The admin needs to log in. The users have access to content which is associated with the admin. For example, the admin allows access to a certain page, then the users can access it, otherwise, they are redirected to a different one where I am doing get requests every 10 seconds to a hidden page where the admins modifies if the user has or hasn't access.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a solution to my problem.

First, the hidden page which is only used as a "signal" telling if the users can proceed, renders yes or no. When the Admin selects yes/no radio button, then the app does an ajax post request to my server, saves the value and renders the hidden page with it.